# How can I edit global styles?

Tags: editor

I'm following this article to edit global styles on my WP site:

- https://wordpress.com/go/web-design/everything-you-need-to-know-about-wordpress-global-styles/
- https://learn.wordpress.org/tutorial/how-to-style-your-site-with-global-styles/

Both above tutorials claim the following: `If I go to Dashboard > Appearance > Editor, I will see *Styles* icon in top left corner`. Furthermore, in the first article there is a screenshot confirming this, and in the second there is an entire video also confirming the same.

However, when I go to Dashboard > Appearance > Editor, I do not see the same screen! I do not see the same options! How is this possible? What am I doing wrong?
I'm attaching a screenshot of the screen I see.[image]

Comment: It may not be supported by your theme. What theme are you using?

Comment: those articles are out of date, notice the WP version it was filmed on is v5.9 and the current version is v6.2. You have to edit a template and go to the top right corner, but this isn't a programming/development question it's a user support question. Also the first link is for wordpress.com, the commercial 3rd party service, which can and do make changes to WordPress that are non-standard. You should ask wp.com support if you're on a wp.com hosted site

Comment: @JacobPeattie it's TwentyTwentyTwo.

Comment: @TomJNowell so sorry if my question is inadequate. I was under the impression that I can ask any wp-related question, not just a programming/dev problem. I am aware what wp.com is, but the tutorial is still applicable to standalone installs. I did notice versions are slightly outdated, but the articles are still official, and I couldn't find anything more up to date. Your advice to go to Editor > Templates > [template] helped. Thanks.

Comment: wp.com has a habit of using newer versions of gutenberg than what come with standard WordPress downloads which isn't always obvious, or have additional features that aren't clearly marked as unique to them. Glad my hint helped :)